# How to use jqGrid Advanced Search /w Serverside PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've been playing around with jqGrid but cant work out how to implement the search functionality. Ideally I'd like to use the 'Advanced Search' - I imagine that when the user submits the advanced search form, the entered data is fired to the url specificed under 'editurl'? Im guessing this URL then outputs the resultset filtered using the search criteria.

My question is how is this actually done? Am I right in the URL data is sent to, and if so how can this data be accessed?

Im fairly decent at jQuery, and good at Javascript- Im using PHP for all server side stuff (expert knowledge, and of mySQL) but cant for the life of me seem to work this out...at present my Java is:

```
var lastsel; 
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'example.php',
    datatype: 'xml',
    hidegrid: false,
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['id','ti', 'na','al','de'],
    colModel :[ 
        {name:'id', index:'id', width:55, hidden:true, key:true, resizable:true}, 
        {name:'ti', index:'ti', width:75, resizable:true,editable:true}, 
        {name:'na', index:'na', width:200, align:'left', resizable:true,editable:true}, 
        {name:'al', index:'al', width:200, align:'left', resizable:true,editable:true}, 
        {name:'de', index:'de', width:400, align:'left', sortable:false, resizable:true,editable:true}
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    height:'100%',
    rowNum:10,
    searchGrid: {multipleSearch:true, caption : 'go'},
    rowList:[50,100,200],
    sortname: 'ticker',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    editurl:'example.php',
    multipleSearch:true,
    caption: 'Definitions'
});
```

All help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if you found your answer anywhere, but i just did it and i can help you a little.

They pass a parameter called filters. Is a json...you have to receive it as a request and transform it in an array.

I work with php, so i used a function called json_decode($yourvar, true).  It transformed the filter in an array. The array is easier to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

As you said the URL contains the search information.

But the search isn't make in the client side, you have to implement it in your server side.

And the code you posted isn't Java, is JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and apologies, Java was a misnomer- Im aware its Javascript (as initially noted).

I know you can grab the search criteria, terms etc in php using $_GET['sOper'] (and similar), however how is the data represented/passed for an advanced search? I imagine its in an array, but how is that array structured? (i.e. serialized etc..).

Comment: I didn't find any documentation of searchGrid (uesed in your example). But in http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html there are demos making search, using php. Did you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to learn this myself, but I'd recommend checking out their PHP search demo at:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

On the left hand side, open the accordion tab and go down to Live Data Manipulation, then click "Searching Data".  You'll see the live example along with code.  This particular example uses XML instead of JSON.

In their example, I don't understand how they pass the search variables to the php code: it just happens.  If it was json, I know it would be in the URL.

In any case, I can see that the data is returned to the HTML page in the same manner as a normal grid populate method: it's returned to jqGrid using an XML format, and jqGrid knows how to take data in that format and run with it.

Hope that helps.